# MySQL adding string to itself

Tags: mysql, sql, string, dynamic, cursor

I'm trying to add string to itself in MySQL in cursor, i need that for my dynamic SQL query.

I have my string set before cursor

```
ESQL3 = "FIRST PART OF QUERY ";
```

Now in cursor i want to add the rest of the query, im using CONCAT() but i feel like its not doing the job.

```
SET @ESQL3 = CONCAT(ESQL3, aggregate_function, "(", table_name, ")" as ", table_name, " , ");
```

The result is declared first part of query + last call of that function.
I've searched a lot for an answer.

Thank you

Comment: You might need further clarification to get a helpful answer, but as written, `, ")" as "` doesn't work.  Perhaps you just need to remove the exta double quote -- `, ") as "`...

Comment: it does work so that is not the problem but htank you for commentgin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to reference the user defined variable, `@ESQL3` as an argument in the `CONCAT` function, rather than the stored program variable  `ESQL3`.

Change this:

```
SET @ESQL3 = CONCAT(ESQL3, ...
```

to this:

```
SET @ESQL3 = CONCAT(@ESQL3, ...
                    ^
```

(MySQL stored program variables and MySQL user-defined variables are two *different* things.  That is,  **`ESQL3`** and **`@ESQL3`** are *not* the same variable. They are two fundamentally different variables.

---

**EDIT**

Also, the rest of the CONCAT arguments look kind of funky. These look okay:

```
, aggregate_function
, "("
, table_name
```

But this doesn't look right:

```
, ")" as ", table_name, " , ");
```

I don't think the "as" keyword is allowed in CONCAT, and that's not going to be seen as a string literal.

Maybe you mean to include "as" as part of the string value, like this:

```
, ") as "
, table_name
, " , "
```

**FOLLOWUP**

You need to *initialize* `@ESQL3`. That's not happening in the code you posted. The scope of the user-defined variable is the **session**, the value of that variable persists across statements. The next time it's referenced in the session, it's going to have whatever value was last assigned to it.

And when you initialize it, leave off the trailing comma. Add the comma when you append the next expression to the SELECT list.

```
SET @ESQL3 = "CREATE TABLE Obroty AS SELECT Towar";
    ^                                            ^
```

Note that we need to initialize the **user-defined variable** which is referenced later.

It matters not one whit what the **stored procedure variable** `ESQL3` is set to. That has *no* relationship to the user-defined variable `@ESQL3`.

Inside the loop, when you are appending to `@ESQL3`, include the comma literal BEFORE the expression, rather than after it. Like this:

```
SET @ESQL3 = CONCAT(@ESQL3, ", ", funkcja, "(", miech, ") as ", miech );
                            ^^^^
```

So, entering the loop, `@ESQL3` is going to have the value

```
CREATE TABLE Obroty AS SELECT Towar
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After the first trip through `read_loop`, it will have a value like

```
CREATE TABLE Obroty AS SELECT Towar, SUM(foo) AS foo
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The next time through the loop, it will have a value like

```
CREATE TABLE Obroty AS SELECT Towar, SUM(foo) AS foo, SUM(bar) AS bar
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When the loop is exited, you'll be ready to append "`FROM whatever`. (Make sure you have the space before the `FROM`.)

Comment: Thank you for that, now it solved my problem but now it wont reset on call so its stacking :D

Comment: It's not clear where the problem is.  If you're looping through the CONCAT to append multiple strings, then initialize the variable to be empty first, then loop through the CONCAT, and then after the loop, run another CONCAT to pre-pend the static part of the SQL text to the string you've generated. Alternately, if the problem is that `@ESQL3` contains SQL text after you execute a query, then re-initialize the variable at the top of the loop. (The fix really depends on what you mean by "its stacking", we can't tell from what we see here.)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cjHTUivi heres the whole code, first part of up to 49th line is irrelevant and serves for some table twisting (weird university assigment). The whole thing starts at 51st. By stacking i mean its adding on every call another SUM(miech)'s to previous result of calling. Im sorry for polish naming. I would like to have @ESQL3 as CREATE TABLE Obroty AS SELECT Towar, SUM(styczen) as styczen, SUM(luty) as luty, SUM(marzec) as marzec FROM Sprzedaz GROUP BY Towar (i forgot to add it)

Comment: I spot one problem, the trailing comma appended to `@ESQL3`. That comma is going to be there when you tack on the `FROM`. And I don't see that user defined variable `@ESQL3` is being initialized. There's a `SET ESQL3 =` statement, but that's an entirely different variable than `@ESQL3`. The at sign (`@`) as the first character of the identifier makes *all* the difference.